# Unable To Load EasyMDE Editor In Blazor Server App Using ServerPrerendered,

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to load this Markdown editor on a standard Blazor page but it won't work. I have all the code on the page as it shows on the page. It's very straightforward.

https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor

I have created a very simple page called `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<textarea id="easymdeeditor"></textarea>
```

I have copied the EasyMDE CSS in the head of the `_host.cshtml` file, and the JS file under the `blazor.server.js` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/easymde/dist/easymde.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/easymde/dist/easymde.min.js"></script>
```

And I have the following code running in the footer of the `_host.cshtml` after the EasyMDE Js file

```
<script>
   const easyMDE = new EasyMDE({element: document.getElementById('easymdeeditor')});
</script>
```

When I run the page, the Editor shows for maybe half a second, then disappears leaving the standard `textbox`? There are no errors in the console.

I am using ServerPrerendered so I assume this is something to do with the double load that you get with ServerPrerendered? Has anyone actually got this running? Should be very simple, but I'm failing at the first hurdle!

Comment: Did you turn off Prerendering and tried again?

Comment: But I think you have to move that getElementById part to OnAfterRender(first:true)